# Testcontainers - Run container with different database in integration test

Tags: java, docker, junit5, testcontainers, thorntail

During the maven package phase I build a docker image of my application:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.spotify</groupId>
    <artifactId>dockerfile-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.dockerfile-plugin}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <repository>archetype/thorntail</repository>
        <tag>${project.version}</tag>
        <buildArgs>
            <JAR_FILE>${project.build.finalName}-thorntail.jar</JAR_FILE>
        </buildArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In my integration test I use this image of my app as follows:

```
@Container
private static GenericContainer apiContainer =
        new GenericContainer("archetype/thorntail:0")
                .withExposedPorts(THORNTAIL_WEB_PORT)
                .waitingFor(
                        Wait.forHttp("/base/api/hello")
                );
```

My question: How can I signal my container that it is running in an integration test and should therefore use a different database e.g. H2?

Comment: Do you use `spring` or something similar or is it just a plain java?

Comment: @SergiiBishyr I use thorntail (https://thorntail.io).

Comment: I can see that thornail, as well as `spring` have the profiles: https://docs.thorntail.io/4.0.0-SNAPSHOT/#_configuration. You can use them to run different configurations for integration tests and production